# Does the Unity WebGL exporter work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Has the Unity WebGL exporter improved in the last year? Thinking about using it for a project but the last time I checked it wasn't fit for purpose..huge file sizes and bugs with different browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I just finished porting my mobile game to WebGL using Unity 2017.1. It has stabilized quite a bit and I found no major issues using it. The biggest annoyance was the long compilation times.

Comment: How are the generated file sizes?

Comment: My WebGL game compiled to about 15mb.  In comparison the Android build compiled to about 41mb.  Granted I shrunk the textures down more for the Web but otherwise I'd say very comparable sizes to Android.  But you pay for it with much longer compile times.  Make sure you follow their suggestions here to help reduce build size: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it to be quite good now in 2017.1. It compresses things pretty nicely and load times are not too bad. If you want to see some examples of different games exported to WebGL, I have a site up called [SIMMER.io](https://simmer.io) to host these games. Most uploads were created in Unity 2017.1.

[image: Screenshot of Unity WebGL game example]

There's also a WebGL compressor asset available here, but I have not tried it: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30335